# How can I locate Y coordinate of my elements in array

Tags: javascript, css, drupal-8

I need some help.

I try to locate Y coordinate of multiple div with the same class (.section-container)
but console.log return me 0 for each div.

(2) [div.section-container, div.section-container]
2 0

Do You have any idea please ?

```js
const sectionSelector = element !== undefined 
                      ? element.querySelectorAll('.section-container') 
                      : false;
    
const sectionArr = Array.from(sectionSelector);
    
const PosY = function() 
  {
  sectionArr.forEach( function(e) 
    {
    const pos = e.getBoundingClientRect();
    const y   = pos.top;
    console.log(y)
    })
  }
    
PosY();
```

Thks for your help !

Comment: please add the html + css of that  --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does changing "const" to "let" for pos and y help?

Comment: @NeilW Uh, the const is inside a function. So const is actually ok.

Comment: what is element in your example ? seems to work well when getting div with document.getElementsByClassName > https://plnkr.co/edit/Mkw29fWA5sAq5CU3?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to use pos.y instead of pos.top?

top is only a relative value, described in MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Comment: Thks Guy for your help ! The div was in Display none. But I have another problem.

How can I return the data (Y coordinates) directly to the const ? 

ex : 
const posY = 1200 ?

Thks a lot !

Comment: do you want to get the y coordinates of the div's in an array? or only want to get the y coodinate of the first value?

Comment: I want the y coordinate of the divs. The final goal : add class with opacity:1 attribute To show divs "section-container" on scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see anything wrong with the code as far as it is given, but we don't have the HTML so I have added some to test things.

The code works fine as long as the HTML is there for it to work on. Hopefully comparing what is in this snippet and what you actually have will throw some light on the problem.

```html
<style>
.section-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}
</style>
<div id="main">
  <div class="section-container"></div>
  <div class="section-container"></div>
  <div class="section-container"></div>
  <div class="section-container"></div>
  <div class="section-container"></div>
</div>
<script>
let element = document.getElementById('main');
const sectionSelector = element !== undefined 
                      ? element.querySelectorAll('.section-container') 
                      : false;
    
const sectionArr = Array.from(sectionSelector);
    
const PosY = function() 
  {
  sectionArr.forEach( function(e) 
    {
    const pos = e.getBoundingClientRect();
    const y   = pos.top;
    console.log(y)
    })
  }   
PosY();
</script>
```